# How do I resize this table in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I'm writing on Rmarkdown and I copied this table:

```
|                 |     January    |     February    |     March  |     April    |     May    |     June    |     July    |     August    |     September    |     October    |     November    |     December    |
|:---------------:|:--------------:|:---------------:|:----------:|:------------:|:----------:|:-----------:|:-----------:|:-------------:|:----------------:|:--------------:|:---------------:|:---------------:|
|      Avocado    |        5       |         6       |      3     |       6      |      3     |       6     |      12     |        4      |         5        |        4       |         8       |         3       |
|     Eggplant    |        14      |        15       |      23    |       22     |      22    |      26     |      25     |       22      |         17       |        22      |        18       |        27       |
|       Lettuce   |        50      |        36       |      41    |       39     |      49    |      48     |      67     |       71      |         48       |        61      |        46       |        51       |
|      Watermelon |        2       |         5       |      2     |       2      |      3     |       2     |       7     |        3      |         4        |        4       |         4       |         4       |
|       Apples    |        0       |         1       |      1     |       0      |      0     |       0     |       0     |        0      |         1        |        1       |         0       |         1       |
|         Pear    |        2       |         0       |      0     |       1      |      0     |       0     |       1     |        1      |         0        |        1       |         1       |         0       |
|      Grapes     |        0       |         0       |      0     |       1      |      0     |       1     |       1     |        1      |         2        |        0       |         1       |         0       |
|       Others    |        2       |         1       |      1     |       2      |      1     |       0     |       1     |        1      |         1        |        1       |         3       |         0       |
```

Nonetheless, the result in my pdf output is this one
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYy1R.png)

How could I fix and resize the table in order to fit it within the borders of the sheet?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load you data as a data frame and then print the pdf table using `kbl()` from {kableExtra}

````
---
title: "Your title"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r}
# load data as a data frame
dat <- data.frame(
  "January" = c(5, 14, 50, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2),
  "February" = c(6, 15, 36, 5, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  "March" = c(3, 23, 41, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1),
  "April" = c(6, 22, 39, 2, 0, 1, 1, 2),
  "May" = c(3, 22, 49, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  "June" = c(6, 26, 48, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0),
  "July" = c(12, 25, 67, 7, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  "August" = c(4, 22, 71, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1),
  "September" = c(5, 17, 48, 4, 1, 0, 2, 1),
  "October" = c(4, 22, 61, 4, 1, 1, 0, 1),
  "November" = c(8, 18, 46, 4, 0, 1, 1, 3),
  "December" = c(3, 27, 51, 4, 1, 0, 0, 0)
) 

# set row names
rownames(dat) <- c("Avocado", "Eggplant", "Lettuce", "Watermelon",
                   " Apples", "Pear", "Grapes", "Others")


library(kableExtra) # import kableExtra to use function kbl()
library(magrittr) # import magrittr to use %>% (a.k.a pipe operator)

# print the data frame as a pdf table
kbl(dat) %>% kable_styling(latex_options = "scale_down")
```
````

[image]

I recommend looking at [{kableExtra} documentation](https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf) for more options.